# Get the fonts/Myfont.ttf linked files from local folder

Tags: android, classloader, truetype, typeface

i have folder called mydata in My project in that i have fonts/Myfont.ttf files which are linked and not copied, Now how can i get the source of this ttf file and pass it to Typeface ?

I have tried this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromFile("data/fonts/myfont.ttf");
```

But i get this error "native typeface cannot be made android error"

But not working can any one help me on this?

Comment: what do you want? to use this custom font? or anything else with it?

Comment: @StinePike yes i know how to use this custom fonts bu i have some fonts in the local folder and not in assests folder but these files are linked and not copied now how to get this files?

Comment: Move the font file into `assets/`, then use `createFromAsset()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare but the files are linked ? and not copied , i mean the files are shortcuts or alias not directly copied? will it work even its shortcut?

Comment: Symlinks or hardlinks at the OS level into `assets/` may work, though I have never tried this. I would recommend simply copying the file into `assets/`.

Comment: @Goofy have you got solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404145/register-font-is-corrupting-ttf-file