# javafx migration to java 11 - characters encoding issue

Tags: java, javafx

I migrated an existing javafx application from java 8 to java 11. I verified that all files were encoded and saved with UTF-8. My system is windows 10 with java 11.0.5. I can't see the euro symbol in the tables, nor the accented characters inside the dialog boxes. I also noticed that the font icons are not displayed either.

I loaded this module

```
--module-path
"D:\JAVA\HomeManagement\lib\jar"
--add-modules
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.base,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.swt
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=javafx.controls
--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=javafx.controls
```

Comment: Are you using the Unicode string literal - \u20AC - for the Euro symbol?

Comment: No. I use the symbol directly as well as the accented characters. For example è is printed as ?

Comment: After clean all works fine but font awesome 
continue to not be displayed.

Comment: For icon fonts the problem solved by following this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404145/register-font-is-corrupting-ttf-file